# grpc python measure response time

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

How can I measure the full time grpc-python takes to handle a request?
So far the best I can do is:

```
def Run(self, request, context):
   start = time.time()
   # service code...
   end = time.time()
   return myservice_stub.Response()
```

But this doesn't measure how much time grpc takes to serialize the request, response, to transfer it over the network..  and so on. I'm looking for a way to "hook" into these steps.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/#request-streaming-rpc

Comment: Yes, didn't find. And this link doesn't answer my question, it only measures the python code inside the request handler

Comment: You can try adding `time.time()` before and after calling `Run(self, request, context` method.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Is this for benchmarking?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to figure what is the overhead of the grpc serialization, and other things that run before my actual code

Answer (score 0):

You can measure on the client side:

```
start = time.time()
response = stub.Run(request)
total_end_to_end = time.time() - start
```

Then you can get the total overhead (serialization, transfer) by reducing the computation of the `Run` method.

To automate the process, you can add (at least for the sake of the test) the computation time as a field to the `myservice_stub.Response`.

Comment: I've already done that, though this will include network + overhead in the server. I hope to measure the overhead in the server alone

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interceptor for this. the package [grpc-interceptors](https://pypi.org/project/grpc-interceptor/) simplifies creating interceptors.

```py
import logging
import time
from typing import Callable, Any
import grpc

class RequestLoggingInterceptor(ServerInterceptor):
    def intercept(
        self,
        method: Callable,
        request: Any,
        context: grpc.ServicerContext,
        method_name: str,
    ) -> Any:
        start_time = time.monotonic()
        ip = context.peer().split(":")[1]

        try:
            start = datetime.now()
            return method(request, context)
        finally:
            request_time = time.monotonic() - start_time
            logging.info(
                f"{ip} -- {datetime.now()} -- {method_name} -- {request_time}s"
            )
```